# How to know if X and Y have coauthored?

Tags: soft-question

Is there any tool where one can figure out if two people have coauthored or not? Like the tool where one can figure out somebody's *Erdos* _number_ .

Comment: related: [1](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/6607/)

Answer (score 17):

In computer science, [DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/index.html) might be a better idea than MathSciNet. Your own page in DBLP lists all your coauthors; the database is certainly not complete, but usually the information is correct.

You can also try to use Google Scholar, with a search similar to this:

```
author:foo author:bar
```

As always with Google Scholar, double-check the results.

Comment: I just tried comparing DBLP to MathSciNet for my own list of co-authors. DBLP was quite a bit more complete than MathSciNet but there was at least one pair of co-authors that MathSciNet found and DBLP missed (on a math paper, of course — with Greg Kuperberg and Günter Ziegler). So combining answers from multiple sources is probably a better answer than just picking a single database.

Answer (score 14):

Complementing [Jukka's answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/how-to-know-if-x-and-y-have-coauthored/2580#2580): There's a Java-based tool called [DBL-Browser](http://dbis.uni-trier.de/DBL-Browser/), which uses DBLP and provides you with lots of graphical charts, like this:

[image]

It uses the same database as DBLP. It can be used both online or offline. You must download the whole [DBLP database](http://dbis.uni-trier.de/DBL-Browser/downloads/dblpCOMP.zip) (~ 60MB) in order to use it offline.

Comment: Is there a recent version of the DBLP database for download?

Comment: The current version seems to be 2-3 years old. I don't know if there's a newer version, but I'm eager to know too. Contacting the author might be the best option.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 9):

Try the [MathSciNet Collaboration Distance Calculator](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/collaborationDistance.html).

Comment: the reference to the Erdős number calculator is to MathSciNet, so I think the OP is looking for something similar but based on DBLP or other CS-focused publications databases.

Comment: Actually, the MathSciNet listing of coauthors of a given author is a different feature than its collaboration distance calculator.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Microsoft Academic Search](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/) if you're looking for graphical display of coauthor graphs, although it does not appear to be a finished product content-wise.

Comment: But like Google Scholar, ALWAYS double-check the results.