# What is the best place to get BibTeX entries for ICLR and other machine learning papers?

Tags: machine-learning, research-practice, paper-review, bibliography

dblp seems the best i found so far (as also mentioned in the comments and in [What is the best place to get BibTeX entries for computer science articles ?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6607/what-is-the-best-place-to-get-bibtex-entries-for-computer-science-articles)) but even there some papers from NIPS workshops and ICLR in general are not listed as such and are listed simply as CoRR papers.

For example "Neural Machine Translation by Jointly Learning to Align and Translate" 
https://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/journals/corr/BahdanauCB14 
although after writing the question i'm finding that most papers are referencing the NMT paper also as CoRR/arXiv. I also didn't find proceedings of ICLR so maybe it's a general issue only with ICLR papers and some conference workshops.

Comment: I like DBLP: https://dblp.uni-trier.de/. It has BibTex entries for conference articles across CS.

Comment: i tried with dblp as i mentioned in the question but i'm having issues with iclr papers and some nips papers as well. i added an example in the question

Comment: There's also The Collection of Computer Science Bibliographies maintained here: https://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an update, I noticed that DBLP has added ICLR to tracking as of today. Now it has ICLR papers and their bibtex available at https://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/conf/iclr/

Answer (score 9):

- For NeurIPS (previously NIPS), the [NeurIPS website](https://papers.neurips.cc/) itself is a good source: look for a paper, go to its page, and click on the "BibTex" link. Here is a random sample (!):

[image]

- ICML, COLT, and JMLR appear to have similar BibTex-ready websites: see http://proceedings.mlr.press/. For instance, going to the abstract of a randomly chosen paper from ICML'15:

[image]

- ICLR does not seem to have this in place; for instance, even checking on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9430221802571417838&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5), the paper you point out is cited *a lot* (~4k times), but *always* as the arXiv version. For conferences or workshops using [OpenReview](https://openreview.net/), such as ICLR'18 *(I believe it was the first time for this conference)*, you can get *some* BibTex entry by [clicking on a specific paper](https://openreview.net/group?id=ICLR.cc/2018/Conference), and selecting "Show BibTex":
  [image]
  However, it is unclear to me the resulting citation is better that the ArXiv one.

Comment: thanks for the tip. it made me go back and check on dblp and actually the paper you mentioned is listed there https://dblp.uni-trier.de/rec/bibtex/conf/nips/AtkesonS07 along with all other papers i tried. it seems only some workshop papers are not listed which was the paper i was trying to reference when i wrote the question. i updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @user2160809 As far as I can tell, ICLR *does* have proceedings, but no way to generate BibTex mentioning that (including [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/), which itself is a good default place to look at for citations if everything else fails). As for workshops, in general it'll depend. If there are no official proceedings, for instance, it's unlikely you'll find anything...

Comment: @user2160809 See my edit.